# How to unpublish or remove all auto-generated subtitles from all my YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I have more than 200 videos uploaded to YouTube with YouTube-generated subtitles.

Now I need to unpublish or remove all of them.

Doing this by hand would take ages.

Is there any batch-way how to do it?